# how to send an array as xml response in php

Tags: php, xml, arrays

i want to send xml response. I tried following code. but does not print array element but only print "array". Please tell me where i am wrong?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("video_link");

    try {   
        $query = "select * from upload_video";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

    }
    catch(Exception $ex) {

        $response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
            $response .= '<response><status>'.'0'.'</status>';
        $response = $response.'<remarks>'.'Error'.'</remarks></response>';
        header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        echo $response;
    }

    $n = mysql_num_rows($result);

    for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $url = mysql_result($result,$i,'url');

        $store[] = array("url" => $url);     

            }

            $response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
            $response .= '<response><status>'.'1'.'</status>';
        $response = $response.'<remarks>'.$store.'</remarks></response>';
        header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        echo $response;

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert array to SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

Comment: i tried that code but problem is same..it print "Array" instead of array elenment

Comment: What do you want your XML output to look like?

Comment: see [this](http://davidwalsh.name/watch-post-save-php-post-data-xml).

Comment: i want my XML output like this: <response>
<status>1</status>
<remarks>url1, url2,...</remarks>
</response>

Comment: Then why not `join(',', $store)`?

Comment: by using join(',', $store) it gves the output like this: <status>1</status> <remarks> Array,Array ,...</remarks> </response>

Comment: Replace $store[] = array() with $store[] = $url; and use the join solution mentioned above.

Comment: actually wants the output like this: <status>1</status> <remarks> "url1" "url2"...</remarks> </response>

Comment: You have to write your own strings for each element as you did in the surrounding code. PHP will not do this for you. SimpleXML can do this but needs some very different code to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to write the XML as you see fit instead of your for loop if you want the list items as XML nodes :

```
$list = "";
for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $url = mysql_result($result,$i,'url');
    $list .= "<item>".$url."</item>";
 }
```

Or simply use implode on your $store array if a comma seperated list is enough:

```
$response = $response.'<remarks>'.implode(", ", $store).'</remarks></response>';
```